# JQuery UI Date Picker minDate and Date Range Seemingly Pretty Broken

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date

When i set the minDate var to something below 2001, it just won't go below 2001 for the lower limit.

I've tried inserting the minDate value as a string, number, or Date object (as the documentation says you can use any of all 3 types)

Regardless of how i enter the value, it will not go below 2001.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Post your datepicker init code, maybe there's something wrong in a place where you didn't expect it.

Comment: @Till i think he is using the changeYear option without setting yearRange that defaults at ten years

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti i saw your answer and what you describe definitely looks like a possible culprit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is due to the fact that if you display the year with the option `changeYear` you must also set [yearRange](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange) that otherwise default at +10:-10
For example:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
minDate: "-20Y",//go back 20 years
changeYear:true,//show a drop down to change year
maxDate: "+1M +10D", 
yearRange: 'c-100:c+10'//Show up to 100 years before and ten years after in the dropdown
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rUq7M/

Comment: I also needed the `yearRange` part. Nice and simple answer.

Comment: Good call on this; they should make this more obvious, I feel.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to like this: The values given here are just for illustration purpose, you need to use values based on your requirements.

```
$(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                yearRange: '1934:2004',
                defaultDate: '1980-01-01'
            });
        });
```