# how to set year in dropdown of jquery ui calender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have to show a datepicker for date of birth, since the year range will be about 80 years I am using the following code.

```
    $('#<%=txtdob.ClientID%>').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange: 'c-100:c-20'
    });
```

it is working but whenever we change the year range it goes back 100 years!. I think I am missing something . Fiddler code is-->
http://jsfiddle.net/MCheP/
Please help..

Edit: when textbox is clicked calender show up. but when I change year from 1914 to say 1920 it shows 1820 instead of 1920.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following for `yearRange`:

```
yearRange: "-80:+0",
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/MCheP/1)**

Comment: thankx got it, I wrote c because I saw it from here -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329357/jquery-ui-date-picker-mindate-and-date-range-seemingly-pretty-broken and thought it is right.

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a `c` in there ?

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    yearRange: '-100:-20',
    defaultDate: '-100y'
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCheP/5/)

the leading `c` sets the range relative to the selected date, so when you select a date, it sets the range back another 100 years from that date. To keep the range static you remove the `c`

Comment: Please check link, on selecting 23rd jan, 1914, text box shows '23/01/2014'. Is it issue or am i missing something?

Comment: @ram - If you're going to have a year range not including the current year, you should set the default date back 100 years as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange: '-100:-20',
        defaultDate: '-100y'
    });
```

Demo
    http://jsfiddle.net/MCheP/6/

Comment: Please cross check your link. It is not working properly when date is selected. Giving me something lik '16/01/YYYY' in textbox when selected 16th Jan, 1914.

Comment: Not it is giving issue as per original post's issue. On selecting 23rd jan, 1914, text box shows '23/01/2014'. :)

Comment: I am doing like this. Open fiddle link, click on any date without changing year dropdown.

Comment: @ram ,please check now

Answer (score 0):

please see the documentation

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

the actual syntax/example is

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ yearRange: "2002:2012" });
```

You can also use it like this also

```
yearRange: "-100:-20"
```

Answer (score 0):

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate: "-100Y", 
            maxDate: "-20Y"
        });